# Nvidia X server settings missing PRIME profiles tab

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg, ubuntu-drivers, gpu-driver

This was solved by Pilot6, I had Secure Boot enabled on my Acer. Entered BIOS by F2, created a Supervisor password, disabled secure boot then ran glmark2.

[nvidia_WORKS_NOW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHTC0.png)

---

I've recently installed Ubuntu 17.1 (yesterday) and I'm having trouble getting Ubuntu to recognise my Nvidia card (GeForce 1050Ti).
It's a bit of a nightmare, the windows my acer nitro 5 shipped with had everything legit but I'm not that tech savvy.

The 3d rendering initiated by glmark2 used my intel chip and not the independent video card.  I installed the propriety drivers from the software center and blacklisted nouveau. I think this was done automatically by the propriety drivers, I did it too though becuase I was following different forum answers trying to get this sorted. Here's some system output:

```
loki@loki-Nitro-AN515-51:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591b (rev 04)
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 118a
Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_384_drm, nvidia_384
```

So it definitely sees the card is there. I'm a little worried about the multiple kernal modules for the card though.

MY ultimate question (because I think it relates to how I'm going to get to use my graphics card for gaming) is this:
when I run nvidia-settings, there is no prime profiles tab. As shown in the picture link below

[nvidia-settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0ihi.png)

Both graphics cards have [VGA controller] appended. I'm hoping this will be changed when I have the tabs from nvidia-settings up.

```
lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:591b] (rev 04) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:118a]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 320
Memory at a2000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
[virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915

00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:a12f] (rev 31) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [1025:118a]
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile] [10de:1c8c] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile] [1025:118b]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
Memory at a3000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
I/O ports at 4000 [disabled] [size=128]
Expansion ROM at a4000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_384_drm, nvidia_384
```

It doesn't actually say nvidia driver in use, but I have selected the thing from the additional drivers tab on Software & Updates.

[additionalDrivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1VG2.png)

I would deeply appreciate any help. I don't want to go back to Windows. Thanks for reading.

Comment: The driver is installed but not used because of Secure Boot. Disable it in BIOS. Run `sudo modprobe nvidia_384` and you'll see.

Comment: Pilot6!  Thank you so much!

That was totally it. Secure boot disabled, it just ran. That is amazing, thank you.